# I use the DrawerLayout contain Toolbar, but the Toolbar can not display Completely

Tags: android, toolbar

I want to use DrawerLayout contain Toolbar and my content layout ,but when I finish my function, the effect follow as follows:
[effect1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmITJ.png),
[effect2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daRCz.png)

this is my xml:

```
    <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <!-- The content view -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/user_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/gray_background1">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/flay_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </FrameLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/layout_player"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Your drawer view. This can be any view, LinearLayout
         is just an example. As we have set fitSystemWindows=true
         this will be displayed under the status bar. -->
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:subtitleTextColor="?attr/colorAccent"
    app:theme="@style/MyToolbar">

    <!-- toolbar content -->

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I don't know why the toolbar be cover by the status bar,rather than underbelow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the app theme as that in mainfest file

```
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: do you want to hide status bar totally?

Comment: try to use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the root view of your layout

Comment: your method is effective, I add this `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in my root view.